# Why do I get DONE after AUTH LOGIN command?

Tags: ssl, openssl, smtp, certificate, telnet

I am trying to connect to my server SMTP on Windows 2012 R2 server on which is installed a RapidSSL 256 bit certificate. I need to test if the SMTP server can send email to one of our customers which seems to have problem with the certificate. This is the command I launch:

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect www.omniservice2.it:25 -crlf
```

and I get this:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
0 s:/CN=www.omniservice2.it
i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA
1 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA
i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=www.omniservice2.it
issuer=/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3697 bytes and written 363 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
  Protocol  : TLSv1
  Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
  Session-ID: ...
  Session-ID-ctx: 
  Master-Key: ...
Key-Arg   : None
Start Time: 1487243991
Timeout   : 300 (sec)
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
250 OK
```

Then I go with:

```
HELO

AUTH LOGIN
```

and I enter username/password encoded in base64. Credentials are correct and they are normal Windows authentication username/password and they are correctly used by all our .NET application to access the SMTP server.
So, credentials encoded in base64 are surely correct but after entering them, I am prompted DONE and the connection is closed and the shell returns.
What does this mean?

**UPDATE**

Here's the sequence of my commands:

```
>HELO
250 www.omniservice2.it Hello [37.159.171.6]
>AUTH LOGIN
>334 VNXlcm5hbWU6
(my Windows username encoded in base64)
>334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
(my Windows password encoded in base 64)
>DONE
>prompt returned here
```

If, after HELO, I send a `STARTTLS` command, it tells me there is an already started TLS Session

Comment: Unfortunately you only show the part before it gets interesting. Please show exactly which commands you send (but hide the real login information) and what exactly you receive back.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: thank you for your kind comment. Have a look at my updated question if you want

Comment: That's strange. I've tried with of course the wrong credentials and get a proper response (code 553) back.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yes, I know. If you try with wrong credentials the messages you receive are the ones expected but with the right this happens. I've read in some microsoft forum this could be a sort of "bug" (an improper term but I don't know how to call it) of SMTP server... my problem is that I cannot test why it's not able to send emails to that customers if I cannot access it...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww: I am going to post to Super User... sorry. I had tought to post here because both in Super User and in Server Fault they never reply...

Comment: @jww: why have you removed your comment? you were totally right about people in Server Fault. I told them directly many times. Anyway I don't know if I can post on Unix/Linux Q&A because my server is Windows...I was using openssl simply as tester

Comment: @Lory - I did not remove it. Probably one of the moderators. They don't like to be called out. As far as the Windows server, keep the problem framed as a protocol problem with the Linux client. I think interop makes good questions.

Answer (score 1):

AUTH LOGIN or any AUTH command is not valid after HELO, you must connect with EHLO for AUTH to work.

Answer (score 0):

If either your username or password in base64 format start with a capital "Q" open ssl will return DONE.

Similarly if they start with an "R" the connection will be RENEGOTIATED.

To avoid this try using the AUTH PLAIN and pass your credentials on the same line:

```
EHLO <example.org>
AUTH PLAIN <base64>
...
```

Comment: I concur with your diagnostic. It is more than plausible that one of the two base64 encoded strings began with "Q".
But I see  another solution instead of using AUTH PLAIN: you can use the -nocommands flag in openssl s_client. 
That flag disables the interactive command letters.